# I am using the length of an array to map out Dropdown inputs. But I want them to behave separately

Tags: reactjs, react-native

As of now, the user selects an option from the dropdown menu, and then the chosen value is supposed to display. If they choose "A", they will see "A". The problem is, once I choose "A" from one dropdown, the rest of the mapped dropdowns show the same. How do I isolate them to be their own things?

I know I'm not wording this well, I hope it makes sense

This is my code, there is some bulk I removed for easier/quicker reading, but I think I included the necessary things

```
const DrawStaff = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");


  const data = [
    { label: "A", value: "A" },
    { label: "B", value: "B" },
    { label: "C", value: "C" },
    { label: "D", value: "D" },
    { label: "E", value: "E" },
    { label: "F", value: "F" },
    { label: "G", value: "G" }
  ];

  const list = () => {
    return cy.map((element, i) => {
      if (!cy[i]) {
        console.log(false);       
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>           
            <Dropdown
              value={value}
              data={data}
              onChange={(item) => {
                setValue(item.value);
              }}
              labelField="label"
              valueField="value"
              placeholder="SELECT NOTE"
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    });  return <View style={styles.staves}>{list()}</View>;
  };

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    flexDirection: "column"
  }
});
```

How do I make each dropdown it's own man?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the state per Dropdown:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker'

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState({});

  const data = [
    { label: "A", value: "A" },
    { label: "B", value: "B" },
    { label: "C", value: "C" },
    { label: "D", value: "D" },
    { label: "E", value: "E" },
    { label: "F", value: "F" },
    { label: "G", value: "G" }
  ];

  const list = () => {
    return data.map((element, i) => {
      if (!data[i]) {
        console.log(false);       
      } else {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>           
            <Dropdown
              value={value}
              data={data}
              onChange={(item) => {
                setValue({[item.value]:item.value});
              }}
              labelField="label"
              valueField="value"
              placeholder="SELECT NOTE"
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    });
  };
  return <View style={styles.staves}>{list()}</View>;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    flexDirection: "column"
  }
});
```